# Передача entity из jquery в spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

Есть класс Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users implements Serializable{
    private BigInteger id;
    private String login;
    private BigInteger stuffId;
    private String password;
    private String last_name;
    private String first_name;
    private String middle_name;
    private String email;
    private int office_id;
    private String state;
    private Set<Roles> roles;
    private Stuffs userStuff;
    private MailingGroups mailingGroups;

    public Users(){

    }

    public Users(String id, String login){
        this.id = new BigInteger(id);
        this.login = login;
    }

    //Геттеры и сеттеры

}
```

Есть класс MailingGroups:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "MailingGroups")
public class MailingGroups implements Serializable{
    private BigInteger id;
    private String mailingGroup;
    private List<Users> users;

    //Геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Есть controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/newmailgroup" }, produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody GenericResponse saveGroup(@RequestBody MailingGroups mailingGroups) {
        GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();
        mailingGroups = mailingGroupsService.create(mailingGroups);
        response.setMessage("Группа " + mailingGroups.getMailingGroup() + " успешно добавлена.");

        return response;
    }
```

Есть JavaScript код:

```
function saveGroup() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    var users = [];
    $('#users').find(':selected').each(function(i, selected){
        users[i] = JSON.stringify({id: $(selected).val()});
    });
    var jsonUsers = JSON.stringify(users);


    var mailGroup = ({"mailingGroup" : $('#mGroup').val(), "users" : users});

    $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0);
    $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0);

    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url : "newmailgroup",
        data : JSON.stringify(mailGroup),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            $('#message').append(data.message);
            $('#mGroup').val('');
            closeLoader();

            $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 3).css('opacity', 0.8);
            $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 5).css('opacity', 1);

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            show(e);
            closeLoader();
            $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 3).css('opacity', 0.8);
            $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 5).css('opacity', 0.8);
        }
    });

}
```

Есть конвертер:

```
public class StringToUserConverter implements Converter<String, Users> {

    //@Autowired
    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public StringToUserConverter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Users convert(String id) {
        Users user = null;
        try{
            BigInteger IntId = new BigInteger(id);
            user = userService.findUserById(IntId);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            user = userService.findByLogin(id);
        }

        System.out.println("User : " + user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Если поставить users: null, то группу сохраняет, если делать так, как описано в js, то до controller'а не доходит запрос. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подозреваю в js коде у пользователя есть лишнее поле. Попробуйте `var mailGroup = ({"mailingGroup" : $('#mGroup').val(), "users" : [{id:1}]});`, если пройдет, то поле точно лишнее есть.

Comment: MrFylypenko, группа записалась, но вместо того, чтобы конвертировать id в users, просто записалось в userid "1". Я бы хотел, чтобы сразу записывался user. Не уж то придётся искать usera по id и добавлять его? Может надо какой-то конвертер для json?

Comment: Не совсем понял что Вы хотите сделать. Сюдя по вопросу это передать  `entity` в контроллер. А вот из текущей версии вопроса как и куда сохранить непонятно. Опишите подробней проблему.

Comment: У меня есть entity MailingGroups, в ней есть поле List<Users> users. Я хочу, чтобы при передаче из jquery в контроллер у меня заполнялось это поле конкретным user'ом. Есть конвертер, который из id user'a делает самого user'a так сказать на лету, но это если передавать без использования jquery. При способе, который Вы рекомендовали попробовать, в сущность MailingGroups записывается только id user'a, а хотелось бы получить конкретный объект user со всеми полями. Но не пойму как это сделать, не используя "костыли".

Comment: В указанном js когде функция `JSON.stringify` должна использоваться только 1 раз, во время отправки запроса, в других местах не нужно. Также добавление элементов в массив - `users.push({id: $(selected).val()})`. На сервер передается список юзеров, но только их ИД, но можно указать и другие поля, т.е. передать из с фронтенда. А получение пользователя на сервере по его ИД это нормально, не костыль, и займет 3 строки.

Comment: JSON.stringify убрал, воспользовался users.push({id: $(selected).val()}). Оформите, как отдельный ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его, как ответ, который мне помог. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До контроллера "может не доходить" запрос, поскольку в десериализатор доходит не валидный json объект, который не совпадает с описанным классом (например, лишние поля или неправильный тип данных). Такое строгое поведение у десериализатора по умолчанию.

В приведенном js коде формируется неправильный json объект, а именно: неправильно используется функция `JSON.stringify` и добавление элементов в массив. Отредактированная версия должна быть такая:

```
function saveGroup() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    var users = [];
    $('#users').find(':selected').each(function(i, selected){
        //users[i] = JSON.stringify({id: $(selected).val()}); //неправильно
        //правильно push и без JSON.stringify
        users.push({id: $(selected).val()});
    });
    //var jsonUsers = JSON.stringify(users); //неправильно
    var jsonUsers = users; //тут не нужно JSON.stringify

    var mailGroup = ({"mailingGroup" : $('#mGroup').val(), "users" : users});

    $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0);
    $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0);

    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url : "newmailgroup",
        data : JSON.stringify(mailGroup),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            $('#message').append(data.message);
            $('#mGroup').val('');
            closeLoader();

            $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 3).css('opacity', 0.8);
            $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 5).css('opacity', 1);

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            show(e);
            closeLoader();
            $('#mail_overlay').css('z-index', 3).css('opacity', 0.8);
            $('#mail_modal_form').css('z-index', 5).css('opacity', 0.8);
        }
    });

}
```